# RMI service in Amazon-EC2: huge latency

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rmi, latency

I have a Java RMI service that I am trying to deploy on a micro linux instance on Amazon's EC2. I am buffled by the large response time of calls to my server, which take up to two minutes and no less than half a minute.

#### Configuration:

I have opened all traffic to the server. I have taken no other steps to configure the server.

#### How I deploy:

I simply upload the jar file and run the program in a shell.
I run a command like this

> java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=ec2-[*...IP...*].us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com *...[rest of args]*

The program creates and exposes on its own registry, programmatically.

#### The service:

The service does not require significant computing power to perform. It returns instantly when it is run on my laptop. The main objects exchanged are an array of ~5000 elements.

### My question:

Does anyone have an idea on what is the cause of such poor performance, or what steps I could take to determine the cause?

Comment: aside from the really bad performance of t1.micro instances, this might be an issue with DNS resolving, you might want to experiment with -Djava.rmi.server.hostname (using the external / internal hostname, internal / external elastic IP address)